# how to create compatible certificates for docker (Azure Linux vm) from OSX

Tags: linux, azure, ssl, docker, osx-yosemite

I'm trying to follow along with the tutorial ( http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-docker-with-portal/ ) on how to set up docker in the azure portal. As I get to the certificate section and follow a link on running docker in https (http://docs.docker.com/articles/https/) I see the following warning:

```
  Warning: These TLS commands will only generate a working set of certificates on Linux. Mac OS X comes with a version of OpenSSL that is incompatible with the certificates that Docker requires.
```

I found a few post on stackoverflow for similar issues (posted a year ago) but the azure-docker extensions are new, those post are irrelevant. The issue appears to be related to the OpenSSL version in OSX.

Thanks!

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: The best way I've found to achieve this is to run a management VM in Azure and then setup your Docker container host from there. That way OpenSSL is OK and the certificates are present for the Docker management tools. I blogged about the process here: http://blog.siliconvalve.com/2015/01/07/get-started-with-docker-on-azure/

Comment: You're welcome - sorry it doesn't fix the issue on OSX (I had the same on Windows :)).